# how to take an number as input and print a float till that decimal point in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a floating point number, which has 300 numbers after decimal point. How do i take an input and print that number upto that decimal place?

Example: I have
`pi_300 = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273`

And I take input, for ex - 15
i need  `3.141592653589793`
And I take input, for ex - 20
i now need `3.14159265358979323846`
OR

```
another_num = 3345.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

And I take input, for ex - 15
i need `3345.123456789012345`
And I take input, for ex - 18
i now need `3345.123456789012345678`

I've tried `format` method, but it didn't work

Comment: if thats a string, use slicing? e.g. `pi_300[:15]` (with the necessary adjustments)

Comment: And if that's not a string then you don't have all those digits.

Comment: `print('{0:.15f}'.format(pi_300))`

Comment: 15 is example input. the input may differ, like 32. i now need 32 number decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers have limited precision. When you do what you did, you immediately lose most of the decimals. See here:

```
>>> pi_300 = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594
08128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273
>>> print(pi_300)
3.141592653589793
```

There is no way to get more digits from this number, because they are already lost.

Now, if you want to have a higher precision, you can use a `Decimal`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> pi_300 = Decimal('3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822
3172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914
1273')
>>> print(pi_300)
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745
0284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273
```

You can now round it to 15 decimals:

```
>>> print(round(pi_300, 15))
3.141592653589793
```

or more:

```
>>> print(round(pi_300, 25))
3.1415926535897932384626434
```

Note that this may fail with higher number of digits, if it exceeds the precision defined for the `decimal` module:

```
>>> print(round(pi_300, 45))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

But that can be configured as well:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(prec=100))
>>> print(round(pi_300, 45))
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399
```

Answer (score 0):

Use format mini language twice - once to create the format string, once to print:

```
from decimal import Decimal

pi_300 = Decimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273")

def printWith(num, wholeNum, decimNum):
    """Creates a format string and prints it"""
    # create format string
    f = "{{:{}.{}f}}".format(wholeNum,decimNum+1) # 1 decimal more then needed
    t = f.format(num)[:-1] # remove the last (maybe rounded) digit
    # print outout (or better return it)
    print ( t )


printWith(pi_300,2,15)
```

Output:

```
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: @RafaelC not much experience with decimal - but at least that should hold all numbers. I wonder if the print will also keep all of them... - testing it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. How do you suggest i prevent the number rounding. I need the number as it is given.

Comment: @NaveenKumar edited. You format with 1 decimal more, then truncate it before printing it - that way the one youre interested in is not rounded

Answer (score 0):

Format seems to work for me. Here is what I tried.

```
>>>'{0:.6f}'.format(pi_300)
>>>'3.141593'
>>>'{0:.2f}'.format(pi_300)
>>>'3.14'
```

where you change the decimals based on the number after the point in the curly brackets. Its slightly newer formatting syntax than the `%`. Note that formatting it will round the number automatically.

```
>>> round(pi_300, 3)
3.142
>>> '{0:.3f}'.format(pi_300)
'3.142'
```

so, here:

```
>>> def print_rounded(num, to):
...     return '{}'.format(round(num, to))
... 
>>> print_rounded(pi_300, 3)
'3.142'
```